# Hide an image off the bottom of a web page

Tags: html, css

On my website, I want to make an image appear from off the bottom of the page, and then rise to the top of the page, but I can't figure out how to hide the image off the bottom of the page.

How can this be done? I've tried putting `position:relative` and `overflow:hidden` on both the `<body>` and `<html>` tags, and then tried to put the image with a `position:absolute` larger than the size of both `<body>` and `<html>`, but the window always scrolls down -

Examples:

I tried these two versions which do not work -

```
<html style="position:relative">
   <body>
      <img style="top:1000px; position: absolute;" src="~/images/MyImage.png" />
   </body>
</html>

<html>
   <body style="position:relative">
      <img style="top:1000px; position: absolute;" src="~/images/MyImage.png" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean animate it or just make the two pictures appear?

Comment: You need "px" unit with top property, and position:absolute; and left:0 or right:0

Comment: @progysm He actually doesn't need it. And that's the least of his problems, haha.

Comment: have you tried `position:absolute` with `top:-1000px'?

Comment: Shahar -animate it. progysm - I have "px" on my actual code, I fixed my question. Thanks!

Comment: @ABogus Animate it from bottom to top on load?

Comment: I do have position: absolute (I added that to my question). top: -1000px puts it on the top of the browser window..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use fixed positioning which will position the image relative to the viewpor :

```
position: fixed;
```

Afterward the place it anywhere you want using `top/left/bottom/right`. Eg.:

```
top: 100%;
```

which will move it outside the viewport. And then add when you wish to move the image back in:

```
top: 0;
```

for when you wish to activate it.

To make the image animate add the styles to the image:

```
transition: all 1s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
```

## [jsfiddle Example with animation](http://jsfiddle.net/JkFqZ/1/)

CSS

```
img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100%;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

img.active  {
    top: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('img').addClass('active');
    }, 3000)
});
```

HTML

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is:

```
position: absolute; bottom: 0px;
```

This^ makes sure it's at the ABSOLUTE bottom. Meaning, the bottom of the page. Then, when you have this:

```
position: absolute; top: 0px;
```

It's the absolute top.

To animate it, I had to do it a little differently with jQuery. I set `bottom` to be 70%, but that's very negligent. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/KF83U/1/